# Adobe Garamond Pro (otf) with mathdesign

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype, mathdesign

I would like to use the Adobe Garamond Pro (otf) font with `mathdesign`. The readme of the package says:

> The following commercial families are also supported:
>
> - mdpga family     corresponds to    Adobe Garamond Pro     text fonts
> - mdpus family     corresponds to    Adobe Utopia Std       text fonts
> - mdici family     corresponds to    ITC Charter            text fonts
>
> <...>
>
> You have to obtain the commercial text fonts from your favorite
>   reseller. Only the opentype version these fonts are supported. You
>   will need the following files:
>
> - For Adobe Garamond Pro
>
>   AGaramondPro-Regular.otf
>
>   AGaramondPro-Italic.otf
>
>   AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf
>
>   AGaramondPro-SemiboldItalic.otf
>
> <...>
>
> ```
>   Put them in your TEXMF tree in the directory
>
> ${TEXMF}/fonts/opentype/<supplier>/<fontname>
> ```
>
> (Supplier is garamond or itc. The fontname is basically what you
>   want.)
>        You don't need to rename the files. The 'expert' options is useless, since this fonts are provided with small caps and oldstyle
>   figures!

I put the fonts in the directory `.../fonts/opentype/garamond/Adobe Garamond Pro/`, but when I run XeLaTeX on the following code, I get this warning and no pdf:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+mdpgd on input line 185.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file EU1mdpgd.fd. on input line 185.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/mdpgd/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 185.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}% thanks to Ulrike Fisher
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[f(x)=\int g(x)\,dx\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the font but I looking at the code would try the option `adobe-garamond`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, both the options `mdpgd` and `adobe-garamond` are recognized, but then I get the following warning: LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/mdpgd/m/n' undefined (Font) using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 185. And I get no pdf.

Comment: I assume you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. On my machine (Windows 7), your example compiles without error. Looks like a "font installation" problem. Is it necessary to run mktexlsr?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough, I'm using XeLaTeX on Windows7 with MiKTeX 2.9. I run mktexlsr but nothing changed. Did you uncomment the commented line in the code using the `adobe-garamond` option instead? I edited the code with Ulrike suggestion.

Comment: @Luigi : Have you installed (That is, right-click on the file, select Install) the fonts from Windows' point-of-view?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough yes I have. In fact, if I remove the call to mathdesign, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unknown reason the documentation in CTAN is out-of-date. I have uploaded the most recent version.

There is no problem using Adobe Garamond Pro with pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Adobe Garamond]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
    This is a test: $x+y=2$
\end{document}
```

But for the moment, mathdesign doesn't offer Unicode fonts.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I see it works with the `mdpgd` option (otherwise it says `AdobeGaramond option not defined`. I was using the package with XeLaTeX). Is this not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[f(x)=\int g(x)\,dx\]
\end{document}
```

Fonts listed in this example:

```
voss@shania:~> pdffonts Test/demo.pdf
name                                 type           encoding    emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ------------- ------------ --- --- --- ---------
VAQEVQ+AGaramondPro-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C  Identity-H  yes yes yes 5  0
MEBUGK+GaramondNo8-Ita               Type 1C        WinAnsi     yes yes no  6  0
TRHMIW+MathDesign-GM-Regular-OT1-10  Type 1C        Builtin     yes yes no  7  0
VNMJHG+MathDesign-GM-Regular-Extension-10 Type 1C   Builtin     yes yes yes 8  0
```

I have the OTF-Garamond saved in `$HOME/.fonts/GaramondPro/`

Comment: But when you select the option `garamond`, `mathdesign` uses the font URW-Garamond (i.e. Garamond 8 in your log) and I want to use the Adobe Garamond Pro font instead (option `adobe-garamond`).

Comment: But only for the math variables. If you want the pro variant then you have to choose that by setting that via the package `mathspec`. `mathdesign` doesn't know an optional argument `adobe-garamond`

Comment: Yes it does. See the readme of the package and the code as suggested by Ulriche Fischer. It is undocumented in the package manual.

Comment: the current `mathdesign.sty` has no such option! Have a look into the log file!

Comment: Please, see line 104 in `mathdesign.sty`: `\DeclareOption{adobe-garamond}{\gdef\MD@default@family{mdpgd}}`

Comment: In my version there is no such line: v 1.55, current TL 2012

Comment: Ok. The latest version is 2.25.

Comment: I see, it is on CTAN but not on TL2012. However, why do you want to use an OpenType font but for math a Type 1 font? It makes more sense to me to use OpenType XITS math or something else.