# Alternative to default latex fonts

Tags: fonts

May I ask what font is being used in this document? [image]

I am new to latex and I am used to the default font. I am making a lecture not and I wanna know also how to typeset my whole document using this font. Will the symbols get affected too? Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you take the screenshot you posted from a pdf file? If so, and if you use Acrobat or Acrobat Reader, what's the font information you get by clicking on File -> Properties -> Fonts? (If you use another pdf browser, it should have equivalent steps to obtain information about the font, or fonts, used in the document.)

Comment: Seems to be some Garamond

Comment: Hi..I have checked it as you instructed. I see Garamond, Helvetica, Courier...etc there are a lot of fonts used for the entire doc.

Comment: Forget what fonts  are used in that document and focus on  what fonts of the [The LaText Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/) you prefer.

Comment: Hi again..it is actually Adobe Garamond Pro. But how do I use this as my default font style for my latex doc? Will the symbols also change?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534260/garamond-for-both-text-and-math for a related discussion.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112313/231952

Answer (score 0):

Here I put a minimal working example where I use the `garamond` option with `mathdesign`: `\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}`. I use this site https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond/ where you can download and install a clone of garamond: `urw-garamond` (GaramondNo8 Regular, Medium, Italic, and Medium Italic).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document} 

$|2\sin^2 x-1|>\cos x$ $|\cos(2x)|>\cos x$  $\cos(2x)=\cos^2 x- \sin^2 x=2\cos^2 x-1=-(1-2\cos^2 x)$.
\[|2\sin^2 x-1|>\cos x \iff |\cos(2x)|>\cos x \]
\[\cos \alpha -\cos \beta =-2\sin \left( \frac{\alpha +\beta }{2} \right)\sin \left( \frac{\alpha -\beta }{2} \right)\] ad $|\cos (2x)| - \cos x = 0$
$|a|=b \iff a=\pm b$; $\cos(2x)=\pm\cos(x)$.
\end{document}
```